# Base91 string corruption in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, string, iso-8859-1, base91

I'm using Base91 to store an image as a String in a mysql database. When I retrieve the string to convert it back to an image, the string seems to have been corrupted by the database.

I'm sure it's being corrupted in the database because I did an isolated test on a single device of taking a picture, converting it to a Base91 `byte[]`, converting the `byte[]` to a string (using Latin1), converting the string back to `byte[]`, then to an image, and it worked. When I try that with a server in the middle, the images end up broken.

I've tried changing the collation on the specific column on the database from utf8 to ascii to latin1, no luck.

**Code:**

1. *Encoding Picture:*

   ```
   File file1 = new File(path);
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file1);

   byte[] imagesBytes = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
   in.read(imagesBytes, 0, (int) file1.length());

   _picture = new String(Base91.encode(imagesBytes), Base91.CHARSET);
   //appointment.addPicture(new String(Base91.encode(imagesBytes), Base91.CHARSET));
   ```
2. *Storing encoded image:*

   ```
    JsonObject jsonx = new JsonObject();
    jsonx.addProperty("picture", request.getParameter("picture"));

    db.insert("AppointmentPicture",
               "(AppointmentID, picture)values(?,?)",
               new Object[]{appointment.getDbID(), jsonx.toString()},
               false);
   ```
3. *Retrieving the image:*

   ```
   ResultSet rSet = db.query("AppointmentPicture", new String[]{"picture"}, "AppointmentID = ?", new Object[]{appointmentID});
       System.out.println("pictures grabbed");

       JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
       int counter = 0;

       while (rSet.next()) {
           counter++;
           json.addProperty(String.valueOf(counter), rSet.getString("picture"));

       }

       json.addProperty("count", String.valueOf(counter));

       response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
       System.out.println("pictures returned");
   ```
4. *Decoding Image:*

   ```
    String serverResponse = in.readLine();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(serverResponse);

    int count = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("count"));

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(json.getString(String.valueOf(i + 1)));
        byte[] picBytes = j.getString("picture").getBytes(Base91.CHARSET);
        File file = new File(imageDirectory, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpeg");
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        out.write(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length);

    }
   ```

Comment: so, if you try the simple test of taking the base91 encoded string, sending it to the database and reading it back out, how does it compare to the original string?

Comment: thats almost exactly what im doing, write with one device, read with another. I cant copy/paste the raw string onto notepad and do a side by side comparison because it just freezes when i try to do that...too much text i guess...

Comment: do it programmatically from the same device.

Comment: ok, wil let you know how that goes. Il also update my question with the code

Comment: @jtahlborn, please see my updated question with code. Instead of adding the image strings to a collection(which is my goal), im using a single var "_picture" for the isolation test

Comment: what did you find out when you compared the string you put into the db to the string you pulled out of the db?

Comment: some characters seem to get lost during all the parsing.So how do i preserve my string?

Comment: Furthermore, when i eliminate the storage part, the pictures get reconstructed properly, but when i write, then read, the bytes are all screwed up

Comment: I found my error, wasnt decoding properly, this `byte[] picBytes = j.getString("picture").getBytes(Base91.CHARSET);`, should have been this `byte[] picBytes = Base91.decode(j.getString("picture").getBytes(Base91.CHARSET));`....dont know how i missed that